# Why am i able to check more than 1 radio button in this code

Tags: html

```
<body>
    <form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="POST" action="search_user_data.php">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="id_radio"/>ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="surname_radio"/>Surname
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="dob_radio"/>DoB
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `name` attribute in radio button must be the same in radio group.

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="id_radio"/>ID
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="surname_radio"/>Surname
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="dob_radio"/>DoB
```

More info at [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#radio)

Comment: To add, create an id attribute and set that to what you have in name to have a handle to the control.

Comment: I made silly mistake of having different "name" and which is why I was able to select all my radio buttons. This helped me too ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute is what links radio buttons into a group. Use `value` for the actual value of each button.

```
            <td>
                <input type="radio" value="id_radio" name="btn_group"/>ID
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" value="surname_radio" name="btn_group"/>Surname
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" value="dob_radio" name="btn_group"/>DoB
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because they all have a different name. Give them 1 name and they will act as a group:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value='id'/>ID
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value='surname'/>Surname
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value='dob'/>DoB
```

http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the same name for all of the radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have different names for each radio button in order for them to group together, they must have the same name, it looks like you are confusing name and value.

```
<body>
    <form name="search_form" id="search_form" method="POST" action="search_user_data.php">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="id_radio"/>ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="surname_radio"/>Surname
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="dob_radio"/>DoB
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```